# PySpark - Write a DataFrame in number of batch with batch size

Tags: dataframe, loops, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a bigger DataFrame with millions of rows, I want to write the Dataframe in batches of 1000 rows, used below code but its not working.

```
n_splits = 5 //number of batches  ## all remaining data in last batch which count is less than 1000 that also should be written.

# Iterate for each dataframe
i = 0
while  (i <= n_splits):
    # Get the top `each_len` number of rows
    temp_df = copy_df.limit(each_len)

    # Truncate the `copy_df` to remove
    # the contents fetched for `temp_df`
    copy_df = copy_df.subtract(temp_df)

# View the dataframe
temp_df.show(truncate=False)

"""temp_df.select("*").write.mode("append")  \
        .jdbc(nad_config.postgres_url,
              nad_config.postgres_table,
              properties={"user": nad_config.postgres_user, "password": nad_config.postgres_pwd}) \
    .save()
"""
# Increment the split number
i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

as spark documentation, you can control the batch size with the option batchsize while writing to the table so you don't need additional code to control the batch size. here is the link to documentation - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Comment: hi @yogesh garud, I added .option("batchsize", 3)  , and it should insert 10 rows in 4 batch i.e. 3+3+3+1, but its writing all 10 rows together. not working as expected.

Comment: can you please try putting 3 in double quotes ?

Comment: its worked only for a batchsize and loaded only 3 records. remaining 7 didn't get inserted.

Comment: are you executing the entire code that you have written above or just running save() ?

Comment: 1) how do you know it wrote 10 rows together?
2) did it insert 3 rows or insert 10 rows (confused from your comments)
3) the default batch size is 1000 (from the link above)
4) you don't have to control the batch size by `limit` and for loop, just write your entire df